# <p:schedule> sends a timestamp representing the previous day with time of 13:00 instead of current day with time of 0:00

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, timezone, schedule

I have given the following code in web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

I have changed the default TimeZone using

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

In the xhtml file i have specified the timezone as GMT for `<p:schedule`

```
timeZone="GMT"
```

But the dateTime got changed to some other values.It was working fine when no timezone values are given ie; when i put everything as default.

This is the value of the date send from browser in local machine identified using fireBug

```
schedule_end    1384606800000
schedule_start  1384002000000
```

The Date that i get in the bean Class is

```
schedule_start      Sat Nov 09 13:00:00 GMT 2013
schedule_end        Sat Nov 16 13:00:00 GMT 2013
```

And this is what i am expecting

```
schedule_start      Sat Nov 10 00:00:00 GMT 2013
schedule_end        Sat Nov 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013
```

Tested in a IST Timezone GMT+5.30.

Comment: What does your `TimeZone.getDefault()` from inside JSF say?

Comment: @Templar This is the print value 

sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

Comment: The TimeZone is not properly set because you want GMT+5.30 and you have GMT+0. Did you try to set it manually?

Comment: yea i set that as GMT..!! Are you saying that i must set that to client timeZone ie; GMT+5.30

Comment: @Templar I have tried to fix that by setting timezone using this.

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5.30"));

but still the timeZone value is same

sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

Comment: I have set the timeZone as IST so that i got a 19800000 ie; 5.30hr+gmt. But still the problem persist. Now the time value is
Sun Nov 09 18:30:00 IST 2013

Comment: `<p:schedule>`'s timezone attribute is buggy at the moment. So long ago, it used to work but ever since v3.x, the component simply ignores the timezone attribute. In my application, the timezone of the schedule is always the server's timezone, no matter what I put in the timezone attribute. Check out my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096144/primefacess-schedule-ignore-timezone-attribute)

Comment: @Mr.J4mes Is there a bug report for this issue in primfaces bug tracking system?

Comment: @libregeek: I think I saw an issue for this problem once.